# iOS: Keyboard frame change notification bug?

Tags: ios, keyboard

When undocking the keyboard on iOS6 (iPad 3 and Simulator), the keyboard + accessory view reports these frames for UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey (converted to a landscape view):

```
...WillChangeFrameNotification: {{0, 660}, {1024, 396}}
...DidChangeFrameNotification: {{0, 108}, {1024, 396}}
```

Meaning, the keyboard reports that it will soon have a Y coordinate which it normally has when it is closed, namely 660 (which is ok, since keyboard undocking also sends a WillHide notification); but then, it changes its mind and reports that it has changed its frame to an entirely different position (y = 108) instead?!

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

No this isn't a bug. Just convert coordinates on current view:

```
CGRect keyboardFrame = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
CGRect dd  = [self.view convertRect:keyboardFrame fromView:nil];
NSLog(@"keyboard frame %@", NSStringFromCGRect(dd));
```

I added simple [Gist](https://gist.github.com/bimawa/5963666)

Comment: This has nothing to do with conversion of coordinates at all, but with the keyboard reporting different rects in the will- and didchange notifications. Read the question.